# Possible to have Bold text in EXTJS Textarea?

Tags: javascript, extjs

Wondering if I can bold text, and possibly have icons.

I am on v3.2.1 of EXTJS. Thank you for your assistance in this matter.

Comment: Hah! I can't believe I've stumped them all!

Comment: What kind of textarea are you talking about? Are you talking Ext.form.TextArea ? Or something different?

Answer (score 0):

add a css class as

```
 <style type="text/css">
  .bc-tenant textarea {
    font-weight: bold;
}
    </style>
```

Now in the config of the textarea access that css class  which is bc-tenant

```
new Ext.FormPanel({
                height: 100,
                renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
                items: [{
                    xtype: 'textarea',
                    fieldLabel: 'Name',
                    itemCls: 'bc-tenant'
                }]
            });
```